# Different results inside a flatlist vs outside

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm new to React Native so I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong or don't fully understand how flatlists work.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    FlatList
} from 'react-native';

class CategoryScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            refresh: false
        };
    }

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

    _renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
        <View style={ styles.testRowContainer }>
            <View style={ styles.testCategoryColumn }>
                <Text style={ styles.testCategoryText }>Test</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={ styles.testColumnContainer }>
                <Text style={ styles.testCategoryText }>[X]</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={ styles.testColumnContainer }>
                <Text style={ styles.testCategoryText }>[X]</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={ styles.testColumnContainer }>
                <Text style={ styles.testCategoryText }>[X]</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={ styles.testColumnContainer }>
                <Text style={ styles.testCategoryText }>[X]</Text>
            </View>
        </View>     
    );

    render() {

        return (

            <View style={ styles.container }>

                <FlatList
                    data={[{key: 'a'},{key: 'b'},{key: 'c'},{key: 'd'}]}
                    renderItem={this._renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                    extraData={this.state.refresh}
                />

                <View style={ styles.testRowContainer }>
                    <View style={ styles.testCategoryColumn }>
                        <Text style={ styles.testCategoryText }>Test</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={ styles.testColumnContainer }>
                        <Text style={ styles.testCategoryText }>[X]</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={ styles.testColumnContainer }>
                        <Text style={ styles.testCategoryText }>[X]</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={ styles.testColumnContainer }>
                        <Text style={ styles.testCategoryText }>[X]</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={ styles.testColumnContainer }>
                        <Text style={ styles.testCategoryText }>[X]</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>     

            </View>

        );

    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    testRowContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    testColumnContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    testCategoryText: {
        fontSize: 36
    },
    testCategoryColumn: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
});

export default CategoryScreen;
```

Link to running:
https://snack.expo.io/BJJ97oHXH

As you may see (Snack seems to default to the web version - I'm doing the android version and the [x]'s don't show up there), the code works as expected outside of the flatlist, but looks different when I put it inside the flatlist.

I've also tried adding numColumns={5} (or any number other than 1) and when I do that, the data inside flatlist disappears all together.

I've messed around with contentContainerStyle as well but not exactly sure what I'm supposed to put here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `flex` value for the style of testColumnContainer. That's why all `X'`s are out of range.  Perhaps `X` is being displayed on the right side of the cell phone area.

You can remove `flex :1` in `testColumnContainer`

```js
    testColumnContainer: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
```

Comment: You resolved the primary issue! And I did some research on flex so hopefully I understand it a little more now. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your FlatList has no style props. You need to give it style to have the features you want. Otherwise it becomes very difficult to predict what will happen.

Here this should work,

```
...

<FlatList
  style={{ width: '100%' }}
  data={[{key: 'a'},{key: 'b'},{key: 'c'},{key: 'd'}]}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
   extraData={this.state.refresh}
/>

...
```

Comment: Your response partially helped me with the issue! Thank you!